# How to use Astro with WASM in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, vite, webassembly, astrojs, wasm-pack

I would like to use a Web-Assembly Module that I wrote in Rust in my Astro App. I am using TypeScript and the following `astro.config.mjs`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import wasm from "vite-plugin-wasm";
import topLevelAwait from "vite-plugin-top-level-await";

import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";
import react from "@astrojs/react";

export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [wasm(), tailwind(), react()],
  vite: {
    plugins: [wasm(), topLevelAwait()],
  },
});
```

The code using the wasm in a file `functions.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { greet } from "dices";

export function hello(): void {
  let g: string = greet();
  console.log(g);
}
```

Type checking all works fine, however when running with `npm run dev` I encounter the following error:

```
error   WebAssembly.instantiate(): BufferSource argument is empty
CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): BufferSource argument is empty        
    at Module.__vite_ssr_exports__.default (/__vite-plugin-wasm-helper:31:14)  
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)      
    at async eval (/pkg/dices_bg.wasm:6:28)
    at async instantiateModule (file:///D:/code/web-dev/dice-calculator-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:53445:9)
```

When I setup a new Vite project via `npm create vite@latest` with React and TypeScript with the same `functions.ts` file and the following `vite.config.ts` everything works and I can use the functions from the wasm module without issues.

`vite.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

import wasm from "vite-plugin-wasm";
import topLevelAwait from "vite-plugin-top-level-await";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), wasm(), topLevelAwait()],
});
```

Has anyone got WASM working with Astro? I am a bit confused because Astro uses Vite under the hood, but what works fine with just Vite, does not seem to work with Astro.

Answer (score 5):

I found that using

```html
<DistributionCalculatorWrapper client:only="react" />
```

instead of

```html
<DistributionCalculatorWrapper client:load />
```

is a workaround that will work for me. I guess there is some issue that Node.js cannot use the wasm serverside, but if we explicitly have the components using wasm functions being only client side rendered with `client:only="react"` it works.